# Monitoring pending transactions with Go

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, filters

I'm trying to write a program in Go to watch pending transactions, using a geth full node that I'm connected to over websockets. I'm pretty sure I have to use the github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters package to create a new [event system](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters#NewEventSystem), on which I can then call [SubscribePendingTxs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters#EventSystem.SubscribePendingTxs), but I don't know what I should use as the backend.

Comment: `geth` node goes as backend. RPC service should be enabled

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it if you want to make two type of calls at the same time, via Ethereum client and raw RPC (web):

```
; ETH_NODE_RPC_URL="http://localhost:8545"
import(
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc"
)
const RPC_URL = os.Getenv("ETH_NODE_RPC_URL")
rpcclient, err=rpc.DialContext(context.Background(), RPC_URL)
eclient = ethclient.NewClient(rpcclient)

filter := ethereum.FilterQuery{}
filter.FromBlock = big.NewInt(block_num_from)
filter.ToBlock = big.NewInt(block_num_to)
topics := make([]common.Hash,0,1)
signature := common.BytesToHash(evt_name_registered2)
topics = append(topics,signature)
filter.Topics= append(filter.Topics,topics)
filter.Addresses = nil 
logs,err := eclient.FilterLogs(context.Background(),filter)
if err!= nil {
    //
}
for _,log := range logs {
    //
}
```

This code snippet I am using it to scan events, but for pending logs it should be similar. Try to make it work over HTTP first, then switching the medium to web service should be trivial.